# How to get keyset of Map attribute in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I have an attribute in component of type map. I want to get its keyset to iterate in a loop later. How can I can it?

> Attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="fieldAPINameToFilterValueMap" type="Map" />
```

Is there any way to get this like we do in apex using keySet() function?

When I  use following code, I get strange output:

> Code:

```
var fieldAPINameToFilterValueMap=component.get('v.fieldAPINameToFilterValueMap');
    for(var key in fieldAPINameToFilterValueMap){
        console.log('key : '+ key+ 'Map value: ', fieldAPINameToFilterValueMap[key]);;
    }
//Outputs: key:  fieldAPINameToFilterValueMap[key]: {key1: value1, key2:value2}
```

Comment: I don't have the issue. How are you putting values inside your map ?

Comment: I need to Access map values. Let's say I want to add New map in old Map attribute. how should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successfull in taking the key. My bad, the map was not getting populated and I missed it.